# why is the output of this question is 266 -1 10 in turbo c compiler?

Tags: c, pointers, char, unsigned-char, integer-promotion

```
int main(){
    int a, b;
    char *cp;
    a = 511;
    cp = &a;
    b = *cp;
    *cp = 10;
    printf("%d %d %d", a,b,*cp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above code is 266 -1 10
I understood how a = 266, this is because the first byte of a is replaced with the binary eqivalent of 10(*cp = 10) that makes a = 0000 0001 0000 1010 . But I am not able to understand why b is -1.
In the line b = *cp, *cp in binary is 1111 1111 and this is copied to b, but why the end value is -1?

Comment: `cp` is a pointer to a `char`. The `char` type typically can only hold 8 bits. `*cp` is only 8 of the bits used by the `int` variable `a`. When you assign to `*cp` you only modify those specific 8 bits, leaving the remaining unused. Similarly, when you assign from `*cp` you only get those specific 8 bits, not the rest.

Comment: given `cp -> -1 (0xff)` the assignment `int b = *cp;` is equal to `int b = -1;`

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Turbo C compiler, it has expired long ago.

Comment: `cp = &a;` is not valid ISO C  (9899:1990 or later).

Answer (score 1):

To understanf the output try this simple demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a = 511;
    char c = -1;

    printf( "a = %#x, c = %#x\n", a, ( unsigned char )c );
}
```

Its output is

```
a = 0x1ff, c = 0xff
```

It seems the pointer `cp` assigned like

```
cp = &a;
```

points to the less significant byte of the onbject `a` that contains the value `0xff`.

Also it seems that the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char` in the compiled program. In this case the value `0xff` interpreted as a value of an object of the type `char` internally represents the value `-1`. And this value is assigned to the variable `b`

```
b = *cp;
```

So the variable `b` has the value `-1` or in hexadecimal like `0xffffffff` (provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`) due to the propagating the sign bit according to the integer promotions.

Then this byte is overwritten

```
*cp = 10;
```

So now the variable a internally has this value `0x10a` (`10` in hexadecimal is equal to `0x0a`) And in decimal the value is equal to `266`.

As a result in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d %d %d", a,b,*cp);
```

there are outputted `a` that is equal to `266`, `b` that is equal to `-1` and the byte of the variable `a` pointed to by the pointer `cp` that is equal to `10`.